# How to use controller route defined by subcut in the template

Tags: playframework-2.0, subcut

I have a route defined as @com.xyx.abc(str: String) in my routes file.

I want to use this route in a template. I tried using

```
<a href="@com.xyx.abc("temp")/>
```

Obviously didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse routers are generated per package.  So, if you have a package called `com`, a controller called `xyx` and a method called `abc`, then you can do this:

```
@com.routes.xyx.abc("temp")
```

Or if it's a more realistic `@com.example.MyController.abc(str: String)`, then it would be:

```
@com.example.routes.MyController.abc("temp")
```

Comment: I have a package com.example, Controller - HelloController, method - getWorld(str:String). I am using subcut for DI in this controller. Please note, that I do no have a companion object. When I try to add the route in my href as @com.example.HelloController.getWorld("temp"). I get an error HelloController is not a member of package com.example, HelloContoller exists but it has no companion object. Do I have to create the companion object? This controller works just fine when I access it per the path defined in routes file. I run into the issue when I access this controller in the template.

Comment: Note that you're missing **routes** in @com.example.HelloController.getWorld("temp"). In other words it should go like this: @com.example.routes.HelloController.getWorld("temp")

Comment: Clearly I need more sleep or more coffee. Thanks for pointing out Daniel. And of course thanks James.