# Play Framework 2.2.2: JavaScript routing error - required: Int

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

```
object JavaScriptRouters extends Controller{
 def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  import routes.javascript._
  Ok(
   Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
    XyzController.getAbc
   )
  ).as("text/javascript")
 }
}
```

I have the above function as per the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting)

The XyzController is not an object but a class. I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247312/how-to-use-controller-route-defined-by-subcut-in-the-template) about how to use this exact controller in the template. I tried to use the similar route here com.example.controllers.routes.javascript.XyzController.getAbc - In both the cases I get the same error.

```
[error]  found   : play.core.Router.JavascriptReverseRoute
[error]  required: Int
[error]         com.example.controllers.routes.javascript.XyzController.getAbc
[error]                                                                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Also I am using activator v1.2.10

Thanks.